# how to avoid duplication screen in android

Tags: android

I have did a application in android by calling `sub activities(B,C,D,E)` from `main activity(A)`,again calling that `main Activity(A)` from other `sub Activities(B,C,D,E)`by using

```
Intent in = new Intent();
in.setClass(getApplicationContext(), maindashbord.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(in);
```

when i move back from `main Activity` to `login` page by clicking `back` button ,the main Activity displays again and again the times of I have called the subactivity. I have made all other activities in manifest.xml `Android:noHistory="true"`

but I need some static value in mainActivity for next login propose...

how can I replace the duplicate screen display?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

After you call startActivity you can call finish() on the next line to stop the current activity.

To store a value even after the activity is, either use Shared Preferences or Extend the appliation class, which you can access from any activity using the getApplicationContext(). This will return a singleton, so the value will be the same in all activities.

Answer (score 0):

try flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.